# How can one use Amazon's DynamoDBMapper in Scala?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having trouble using Amazon's DynamoDBMapper in Scala code. The main sticking point is getting the JVM to recognize @DynamoDBHashkey when it is used in a case class, like:

`case class MyCoolCaseClass(@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "my_id") myId: String) {}`

Any pointers from someone who has integrated this client library into a Scala project? (I'm hoping to not simply fallback to the low-level API, though that may be a decent decision once exhausting my options with the Mapper).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The DynamoDB mapper uses reflection to find the getters and setters. The SDK assumes Java-style conventions, i.e. that your getters and setters start with "get" or "is", and setters start with "set". You can see the reflection code [on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/DynamoDBReflector.java#L95).

I've been able to get it working, but it feels just like writing Java :(

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "awesome_table")
class TheBestClass {
  private var id : Integer = _

  @DynamoDBHashKey
  def getId() = id
  def setId(_id: Integer) = id = _id
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I had to do this:

```
import annotation.meta.beanGetter
import beans.BeanProperty

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling._

@DynamoDBTable(tableName="DEMOTAB")
case class DemoItem(  // it's a case class for the free stuff, but can be ordinary class
    @(DynamoDBHashKey @beanGetter)  // would not work without meta annotation
    @BeanProperty var id:String,    // must be var or mapper can't instantiate one

    @BeanProperty var number:Integer
) {
  def this() = this(null, null)     // needed by DynamoDB Mapper to instantiate
}
```

Comment: @BeanProperty is the "official" way of interacting with any reflection library that expects you to follow JavaBeans conventions.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful response!  I ran into some issues when using Boolean values.  Specifically, the line `@BooleanBeanProperty var rockstar:Boolean = true` will write the DynamoDb field `rockstar` correctly, but I'm not able to get the property to be named `isRockstar`.  If I try `@BooleanBeanProperty var isRockstar:Boolean = true`, the mapper writes both `rockstar` and `isRockstar`.  Adding `@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "isRockstar")` above doesn't help either.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoshPadnick see MattE's answer body above: The SDK assumes Java-style conventions, i.e. that your getters and setters start with "get" or "is". I don't think you can name your property with begin with `is`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, including the `boolean`

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "User")
case class User(
               @(DynamoDBHashKey @field)
               @(DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey @field)
               @BeanProperty var id: String,

               @(DynamoDBAttribute @field)
               @BeanProperty var firstName: String,

               @(DynamoDBAttribute @field)
               @BeanProperty var lastName: String,

               @(DynamoDBAttribute @field)
               @BeanProperty var active: Boolean
               )
{
  def this() = this(null, null, null, false)
}
```